# delete method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the difference between delete and destroy?

If we generate a scaffold, the default method to remove an date entry is `method: :delete`, while delete is actually not defined in the controller. So how does rails actually figure out what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DELETE` is `HTTP` verb while `destroy` is an action in the controller. If you use resources in your application, `HTTP DELETE` requests are routed to `destroy` action in the controller (unless you change the default behaviour).

`method: :delete` in `link_to` options means that clicking a link would trigger `HTTP DELETE` request.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know:

`Delete` method uses an `SQL DELETE` statement without instantiating the objects or running any callback.

`Destroy` makes the SQL call to the database and deletes the row in the table where the current object is contained, you can still manage the object as long as you have it scoped.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OneZero is clearly referring to http requests mentioning `method: :delete` - not to SQL statements.